# Array Lookup test cases failing

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

So, this is one of two practice questions given by our professor on HackerRank. I came up with the code but the solution only passes 2/5 test cases. I tried thinking about the possible test cases that give an error for around 4 hours, but, I could not wrap my mind around it.

Can someone point out where I went wrong?
Below is the question.

> Alice went for shopping and bought 8 goods costing different prices.
> At the time of billing she realises that she did not have enough
> money. Now, she have decided to remove the item costing maximum amount
> and replace it with another item whose price is same as the item
> costing minimum amount. Help Alice and display final prices on the
> screen.
>
> Note: if more than one element cost maximum price, replace the first
> item.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> Input: 250 1000 50 20 10 100 200 25
>
> Output: 250 10 50 20 10 100 200 25
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> Input: 2500 2500 50 20 10 100 200 25
>
> Output: 10 2500 50 20 10 100 200 25
>
> **Sample Input**: 250 1000 50 20 10 100 200 25
>
> **Sample Output**: 10 2500 50 20 10 100 200 25
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 8 items prices are required
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Prints the final prices of different items after replacing

MY CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int arr[8];
int check=0;
int max=0,min=0;

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
        if(i==0)
        {
            max =arr[0];
            min =arr[0];
        }
        else
            if(arr[i]>max)
            max = arr[i];

            if(arr[i]<min)
            min = arr[i];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==max && check==0)
        {
            arr[i]=min;
            check++;
        }
        cout<<arr[i]<<"  ";
     }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your professor should teach you [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) instead of letting HackerRank do their work. Look at the `else`, is there something missing (compare with the *body* of the `if`)?

Comment: Should probably think about if there are zero items, 1 item,or if all items are priced the same  as edge cases.

Comment: Also, you are trying to memorize the *values* of the max and min, but if you store their *indices* instead, you'll save a loop later.

Comment: This is unfortunate. Judging sites should not be used to teach C++ programming. They have goals far different from education. They may make for some good fun and practice once you know C++, but until then they are best avoided.

Comment: Do you have constraint on limits? i.e. should `int` be replaced by `long long int` or `double`?

Comment: Which is the format of output? You write numbers separated by 2 spaces (and extra 2 space at the end). Similar question for input, can there be several test case in a run?

Comment: What if all the items have the same price?

Comment: @Taekahn: *"bought 8 goods"* That value seems hard coded, so your edge cases seems out of scope.

Comment: @user4581301: identical objects should be handled with `check` variable.

Comment: Yes, but if you input 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4, the output will be 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 and still exceed the amount of money Alice has on hand.

Comment: @Jarod42 trusting inputs is a good pathway to invalid data. Just ask Bobby tables. But it’s not like I spent a lot of energy on this.

Comment: @Taekahn: it is another bad habit for problem from such sites... But should not be the current issue for OP.

Comment: @Bob__ My college did not teach us any proper c++. It was in our course last sem and they taught us absolute basics of the basics (data types ,arrays, etc)  So my knowledge regarding c++ is very limited. Any suggestions on how I can learn more advanced concepts?

Comment: @Jarod42 no it's just one test case with 8 inputs. I was worried about the constraints issue at first as Taekahn mentioned earlier, but I don't think any would be possible considering how the question is framed.

Comment: @Jarod42 After reading your comment, maybe replacing int with an unsigned int could fix the problem? The price of goods cannot be negative, so maybe the failed test cases had negetive values in them.

Comment: @Taekahn the question was obviously poorly framed. I had my doubts about the inputs given in the question, but, my professor just told me to "Go along with it and not think too much about it". And that was my DSA professor.

Comment: The problem statement is pretty vague about the extent of the data values. Please remember that `int` has its limits: https://godbolt.org/z/G8azqPY9v .